# Size mismatch when fitting ResNet34 with 3x390x320 pixel images

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, pytorch, forward, resnet

I tried to apply code for data valuation methods on my dataset. 
In the original source code, images of size 3x32x32 pixels are fed into a fit-method for a ResNet34.

When I try to feed my 3x390x320 pixel images into a fit-method for the ResNet34 the **forward method** of ResNet throws a **RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [10 x 61440], m2: [512 x 10]**

I double checked and the input data for the forward method has the shape [10, 3, 390, 320] (10 pictures). In the source code below I always commented the shape of the tensors. In the original source code, the input data has the shape [10, 3, 32, 32] and works just fine.

How can I modify the model to run on my pictures?

```
def conv3x3(in_planes, out_planes, stride=1):
    return nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False)


class BasicBlock(FitModule):
    expansion = 1

    def __init__(self, in_planes, planes, stride=1):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = conv3x3(in_planes, planes, stride)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv2 = conv3x3(planes, planes)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()
        if stride != 1 or in_planes != self.expansion * planes:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_planes, self.expansion * planes,
                          kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(self.expansion * planes))

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.bn2(self.conv2(out))
        out += self.shortcut(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        return out


class ResNet(FitModule):
    def __init__(self, block, num_blocks, num_classes=10):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.in_planes = 64

        self.conv1 = conv3x3(3, 64)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.layer1 = self._make_layer(block, 64, num_blocks[0], stride=1)
        self.layer2 = self._make_layer(block, 128, num_blocks[1], stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self._make_layer(block, 256, num_blocks[2], stride=2)
        self.layer4 = self._make_layer(block, 512, num_blocks[3], stride=2)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(512 * block.expansion, num_classes)

    def _make_layer(self, block, planes, num_blocks, stride):
        strides = [stride] + [1] * (num_blocks - 1)
        layers = []
        for stride in strides:
            layers.append(block(self.in_planes, planes, stride))
            self.in_planes = planes * block.expansion
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.float()                                         # 10, 3, 390, 320
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x).float()).float()) # 10, 64, 390, 320
        out = self.layer1(out)                                # 10, 64, 390, 320
        out = self.layer2(out)                                # 10, 128, 195, 160
        out = self.layer3(out)                                # 10, 256, 98, 80
        out = self.layer4(out)                                # 10, 512, 49, 40
        out = F.avg_pool2d(out, 4)                            # 10, 512, 12, 10
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)                       # 10, 61440
        out = self.linear(out)                          # runtime exception!
        return out


def ResNet18(num_classes=10):
    return ResNet(PreActBlock, [2, 2, 2, 2], num_classes)
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Fabian